# Сниппеты WebStorm (Live Template). Как использовать название папки, а не файла

Tags: reactjs, ide, webstorm

Создаю сниппет для `React` в `Webstorm` (там они называются `Live Templates`), для того чтобы при вводе, например, `tsc` и нажатии на клавишу `tab` создавалась такая структура

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import * as s from './styled'

interface Props {
 
};

const SomeComponent: FC<Props> = (props) => {
 return (
  <s.Container>
   
  </s.Container>
 )
}

export default SomeComponent
```

Так как в настройке сниппета используется `$TM_FILENAME_BASE$`, то название компонента берётся по названию файла. Т.е. если мы создали файл `some-component`, и в нём воспользуемся сниппетом, то имя функции будет `SomeComponent`.

Но проблема сейчас в том, что по структуре у меня идёт папка с названием компонента, а в нём файл `index.tsx`

Т.е.
не `src > components > some-component.tsx`
а `src > components > some-component > index.tsx`

И поэтому название функции ставится `Index`

**Как настроить сниппет, чтобы он название функции делал по названию папки, а не по названию файла?**

Мой текущий код сниппета:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import * as s from './styled'

interface Props {
 $END$
};

const $TM_FILENAME_BASE$: FC<Props> = (props) => {
 return (
  <s.Container>
   
  </s.Container>
 )
}

export default $TM_FILENAME_BASE$
```

Comment: Может помочь вариант из PhpStorm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702479/get-directory-path-in-phpstorm-live-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы предложила изменить expression для переменной `$TM_FILENAME_BASE$` на `capitalize(camelCase(regularExpression(filePath(), ".*\\\\(.*)\\\\[a-z]*.[a-z]*", "$1")))`; `groovyScript` из ответа в комментарии не работает в WebStorm